# Init Tomcat with spring 3.1.1 failed on ContextLoaderListener

Tags: spring, tomcat

I trying to load Tomcat server with Spring but failing with error(see below),
i use ONLY ONE zip for spring: spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar and did very basic configuration in web.xml
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanx in advance.
Yan

---

### web.xml:

```
       <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/config/controllers.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
```

---

### ERROR:

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:369)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add the `spring-webmvc` dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The missing method is located in `ConfigurableApplicationContext` inside `spring-context*.jar`. So it is not possible that `spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar` is the *only* Spring JAR you have. Try adding:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

to your CLASSPATH.